# Can someone visit USA if was deported from Canada 11 years ago?

Tags: usa, customs-and-immigration

My dad, who is currently 82 year old, was deported from Canada 11 years ago while in cooperation with an immigration officer. All was done in good terms via myself and the immigration officer to assist with the deportation.

Now we’d like my dad to meet us in the USA for a trip, since the process to visit Canada after deportation is extremely complicated and long.

Can my dad enter the states if was deported from Canada or it has no connection at all?

Comment: What nationality is your father?

Comment: What was he deported *for*? Did he overstay a visa? Violate the terms of his visa? Enter illegally? Commit a crime? Become dependent on public benefits? This is relevant as some things, especially a criminal conviction, may make him inadmissible to the US.

Comment: Thank you. He’s from Israel. He stayed beyond his date unknowingly, due to neglect ion of his lawyer who didn’t updated him on his case , and the date passes. He has no criminal issues what so ever. All deportation was done via myself in contact with immigration with fully cooperation and trust both sides.

Comment: Also he wasn’t getting any benefits from Canada. His only sin was staying after time unknowingly.

Comment: Please edit your additional details into your question.

Comment: What about Mexico or a Caribbean island where an Israeli citizen doesn't need a visa?